# Pandas pivot rows into columns with count of occurence per row

Tags: pandas, dataframe, count, pivot-table

I have the following dataframe with one column representing IDs (one same ID can appear several time in the column) and another one representing an occurence of a category for this ID. Each category can have several occurences per ID.

```
    id    category 
    1234  happy     
    4567  sad     
    8910  medium     
    ...............
    1234  happy 
    4567  medium
```

I would like to pivot this table to get the following

```
 id    happy   sad   medium
 1234  2       0     0
 4567  0       1     1
 8910  0       0     1
```

I've tried the following

```
df.pivot_table(index= "id", columns = "category", aggfunc= 'count', fill_value = 0)
```

But it's only returning me the IDs as indexes.

Could anyone help?

Comment: Use `pd.crosstab(df["id"], df["category"])`.

Comment: Alternative ->  `pd.get_dummies(df.set_index('id')).sum(level = 0)`

Comment: @HenryYik thank you the crosstab works really well. Also a reset_index() is necessary afterwards in order to put all the columns at the same level. Can put yoru answer on a post so I can select it and upvote? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `pd.crosstab`:

```
print (pd.crosstab(df["id"], df["category"]))
```

If you want to stick with `pivot_table`, you need to add an extra column as value:

```
print (df.assign(value=0).pivot_table(index="id", columns="category", values="value", aggfunc='count', fill_value=0))

category  happy  medium  sad
id                          
1234          2       0    0
4567          0       1    1
8910          0       1    0
```